# Laravel 5.5 Queue solution with shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron, laravel-5.5

I have searched a lot about this before posting it here and I think still there is no clear answer.
The most elegant solution I found so far is

`$schedule->command('queue:work --daemon')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();`

However, some people has reported that  this was keeping the `schedule:run` command going and was creating several new `queue:work` commands.

In Laravel 5.5, I saw this code
`$schedule->job(new Heartbeat)->everyFiveMinutes();`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling#scheduling-queued-jobs
According to doc:

> The job method may be used to schedule a queued job. This method
>   provides a convenient way to schedule jobs without using the call
>   method to manually create Closures to queue the job

Not sure if this is the right solution to run `queue:work` without any problem?
What are you using for shared hosting where you can not access shell?

Comment: It's not clear in your question - but I get the impression that you do not have a cron tab.  Is there a way in your shared hosting that you can add items to a cron tab?

Comment: I have added item in cron tab `*  *  *  *  *  /usr/local/bin/php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`
So, all I need to know how to add queue worker in `kernel.php` . Laravel 5.5 confused be even more

Comment: @sanjayojha you changed the actual path to artisan right?

Comment: @connormcwood Yes I can

Comment: I guess if it works... it works.  I wouldn't use it for accounting jobs or anything critical though unless you can be certain that the cron tab is a single instance.  If your hosting company runs multiple instances in the cloud, then you could end up with multiple cron tabs on multiple servers and that would likely negate the effect of withoutOverlapping()